# Two HttpGet on the same route in one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following code:

**Non-generic controller:**

```
    [Route(Route)]
    public class DogsController : EntityControllerBase<Dog,DogDto>
    {
        public const string Route = "api/dogs";
        public DogsController(IDogsRepository repository) : base(repository)
        {
        }

        [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(DogDto))]
        [HttpGet)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DogDto>>> Get([FromQuery]int kennelId, [FromQuery]DateTimeOffset birthDate)
        {
            return Ok("Hit non-generic controller");
        }

        protected override DogDto ToDto(Dog instance) =>
            new DogDto(instance.Id,
                instance.BirthDate,
                instance.KennelId
                instance.Name);
    }
```

**Generic controller:**

```
    public abstract class EntityControllerBase<TEntity, TEntityDto> : ControllerBase where TEntity : IIdentifiable<int>
    {
        readonly IRepository<TEntity, int> _repository;

        protected EntityControllerBase(IRepository<TEntity, int> repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        protected abstract TEntityDto ToDto(TEntity instance);

        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(200)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TEntityDto>>> GetAll()
        {
            var instances = await _repository.GetAll();

            return Ok(instances.Select(ToDto));
        }
    }
```

I would like to have the non-generic controller called on `/api/dogs` when the user supplies the query parameters `kennelId` and `birthDate`, and call the generic method otherwise. Right now it always call the generic controller. How do I fix that?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work! Thanks a lot!